# Switch case or if else

Tags: c#, if-statement, windows-ce

I have this long loop of if..else. Can anybody help me in knowing if "switch case" is better for this or "if..else"?

```
if (meals == null)
{
    bfast.Hide();
    lunch_rb.Hide();
    dinner_rb.Hide();
}
else if (meals != null)
{
    if (breakfast != null && lunch == null && dinner == null)
    {
        lunch_rb.Hide();
        dinner_rb.Hide();
    }
    if (breakfast == null && lunch != null && dinner == null)
    {
        bfast.Hide();
        dinner_rb.Hide();
    }
    if (breakfast == null && lunch == null && dinner != null)
    {
        bfast.Hide();
        lunch_rb.Hide();
    }
    if (breakfast != null && lunch != null && dinner == null)
    {
        dinner_rb.Hide();
    }
    if (breakfast != null && lunch == null && dinner != null)
    {
        lunch_rb.Hide();
    }
    if (lunch != null && breakfast == null && dinner != null)
    {
        bfast.Hide();
    }
```

I am developing an application for windows CE 5.0 (if this helps)

Comment: Please take the time to format your questions more sensibly in future.

Comment: Thanks Jon. Will take care in future :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try something like this, As you have condition on multiple variables you will need to make expression for passing it to switch so using if as given below might make it simple.

```
if (breakfast == null)
      bfast.Hide();

if (lunch == null)
      lunch_rb.Hide();

if (dinner == null)
      dinner_rb.Hide();
```

Comment: Thanks Adil, however as you can see I have another condition where user might select two meals. In that case I had to add 3 extra loops.

Comment: If two meals are selected then two of condition will execute and hide two radio buttons

Comment: @saadasharif: For one thing, there are no loops here. For another, please read the answer carefully, and work out what's going to happen if the user *has* chosen two meals...

Comment: I could not see loops in your post but branching if statements?

Comment: my bad , by loops I meant "if statements".

Comment: I have updated my answer with little more explanation. Using if as in asnwer will make it easy to simple and easy to understand and manage.

Answer (score 10):

I think the better solution in this case is:

```
if (breakfast == null)
  bfast.Hide();
if (lunch == null)
  lunch_rb.Hide();
if (dinner == null)
  dinner_rb.Hide();
```

Comment: But you will get null reference exception o_0. How can You call `lunch.Hide()` if **lunch** is null ??? etc...

Comment: @DmytroTsiniavsky was just a typo : it's not lunch.Hide, but lunch_rb.Hide

Comment: we don't need `else if (meals != null)` also, just `else`

Answer (score 1):

For this particular scenario if-else is better because you have complex conditions and that's something switch-case can't do I believe.

Answer (score 0):

For this question, I think `if...else` is good enough. `switch...case` cannot deal with such a complicated situation. Feel free to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Switch case is always better than if...else if because it needs less typing and your codes will be easier to read and understand.I myself just use "else if" when I forget switch's style in exam's!!!

Answer (score 0):

The performance level between `if` and `switch` statements is not much difference. Anyway your code is a mess of conditions. Take into consideration the answer of Pigueiras. Something like

```
bfast.Hide();
lunch_rb.Hide();
dinner_rb.Hide();
if (meals != null) {
  if (breakfast != null)
    bfast.Show();
  if (lunch =! null)
    lunch_rb.Show();
  if (dinner =! null)
    dinner_rb.Show();
}
```